# DIV ativando scroll em outra DIV mesmo com tamanhos diferentes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho duas `div` de mesma altura, mas com conteúdos distintos. E quando eu fizer o *scroll* em uma, eu queria que a outra acompanhasse na mesma (ou ao menos próxima da mesma) posição.

O problema é que os conteúdos delas **não possuem o mesmo tamanho**, e consequentemente o tamanho da barra de rolagem acaba ficando diferente entre elas. Mas mesmo com a diferença de tamanho eu gostaria de fazer o scroll da segunda acompanhar o da primeira, de forma que se eu rolasse até o final da primeira `div` a segunda também deveria ir para o final, mesmo sendo de conteúdo maior.

Não sei se consegui ser claro, [**mas aqui segue um exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7A3Fk/1/) do que eu pretendo fazer.

```
(function () {
    var target = $("#target")[0]; // <== Getting raw element
    $("#source").scroll(function () {
        target.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        target.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
    });
})();
```

Eu utilizei uma solução encontrada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16376869), mas o problema é justamente que o *scroll* da segunda só vai até onde o da primeira termina, ou seja, ele não se comporta da forma devida.

Existe alguma forma de criar um scroll-espelho "inteligente"?

Comment: Você quer que o scroll seja feito proporcionalmente, certo?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Exato, acabei encontrando um site que tem um exemplo bem próximo ao que eu quero: http://dillinger.io - Estou dando uma olhada no código dele, mas qualquer resposta com uma solução ainda é **muito** bem vinda

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://scripterlative.com/files/synchdivscroll.htm

Comment: Me lembrou o [StackEdit.io](https://stackedit.io/).

Comment: @brasofilo esse site que você passou é exatamente o que eu queria, vou dar uma bisbilhotada no repositório dele, valeu!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma ideia aproximada seria utilizar percentuais. Primeiro você precisa saber quantos `px` o scroll `source` se moveu para baixo, para isso fazemos a seguinte regra de 3:

```
scrollTopSource = x
(scrollHeigthSource - clientHeigthSource) = 100
x = 100 * scrollTopSource / (scrollHeigthSource - clientHeigthSource)
```

Depois, temos que converter essa porcentagem para `px` no `target`, para isso utilizaremos a seguinte regra 3:

```
scrollTopTarget = x
(scrollHeigthTarget - clientHeigthTarget) = 100
scrollTopTarget = (scrollHeigthTarget - clientHeigthTarget) * x / 100
```

No código bastaria substituir as seguintes linhas do [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

```js
target.scrollTop = 100 * this.scrollTop / this.scrollTop;
target.scrollLeft = 100 * this.scrollLeft / this.scrollWidth;
```

pelas linhas a seguir:

```js
target.scrollTop = (target.scrollHeight-this.clientHeight) * (100 * this.scrollTop / (this.scrollHeight-this.clientHeight)) / 100;
target.scrollLeft = (target.scrollWidth-this.clientWidth) * (100 * this.scrollLeft / (this.scrollWidth-this.clientWidth)) / 100;
```

Como pode ser visto nesse [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hsU7/), ele precisa de algum ajuste para corrigir problemas de **arredondamento** quando a barra de rolagem chega ao final.

Comment: Apesar deste script não ser tão preciso quanto o do [StackEdit.io](http://stackedit.io/) (comentado pelo @brasofilo), ele functiona muito bem e resolve a minha dúvida. Obrigado.